# AWS Cognito Logout Url format - Required String parameter 'redirect_uri' is not present

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to format the logout rest call to sign out of an AWS Cognito user pool, but can't seem to get it right.

I want to redirect to https://localhost:44333?signout=true after cognito has signed me out.

The following doesn't work and returns "Required String parameter 'redirect_uri' is not present":

```
https://tradingreplay-test.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/error?client_id=***ClientId***&logout_uri=https://localhost:44333?signout=true
```

I have checked and https://localhost:44333 is in the list of valid sign out urls for the app client.

Comment: The query string is probably not allowed.

Comment: You'll get this error if you haven't added the logout URL to the allowed logout URLs list in your Cognito app settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Standard requirement of a [logout URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) is that there's no query string parameter is preserved.
You could possibly set a cookie or handle the request to https://localhost:44333/logout/.

```
https://tradingreplay-test.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/error?client_id=***ClientId***&logout_uri=https://localhost:44333/signout/
```

Since Cognito is [SAML](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/saml-identity-provider.html) compliant, it's probably going to handle the [logout](https://auth0.com/docs/logout/guides/logout-saml-idps) in the same compliant manner by ignoring the query strings or throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks - I had gone through the documentation and didn't really understand what the "com.myclientapp://myclient/logout" part of the logout_uri meant. Where is the logout page set?

Comment: It literally says to use a `GET` request with query parameters in the documentation you linked, just like in the above question. Also, Cognito isn't a SAML provider, it's an OpenID provider. It simply has support for connecting to SAML 3rd party identity providers.

Answer (score 2):

In **Cognito User pool client**, if you miss the **logout url** (which is optional) , this can lead to the same error

In Terraform this was resolved by adding a "**logout_urls**" attribute

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
  name                                 = "test-client"
  user_pool_id                         = aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id
  callback_urls                        = ["https://example.com","https://www.example.com.com"]
  logout_urls = ["https://www.example.com.com"]
```

Answer (score 1):

add logoutUrls when setting up new client,
Define logoutUrls in an array and pass it as oAuth parameters.
like,

```
const googlePoolClient = userPool.addClient("google-client", {
      generateSecret: true,
      supportedIdentityProviders: [UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.GOOGLE],
      oAuth: {
        callbackUrls: callbackUrlList,
        logoutUrls: logoutUrlList,
      },
    });
```